# VideoReader decodes different Frame counts on different computers

Tags: matlab, video, ffmpeg, decoder

I have a large video clip of .avi format(approx 1 hour in length). I read the file using `VideoReader` in Matlab. Surprisingly the number of frames I get on two different computers vary. Below are my system details along with the number of frames I get.

**System 1:**
OS: Windows 8.1 (x64)
Matlab Version: 2013b
Media Package installed: (default, didn't install anything separately. VLC Player is also there on the PC)
Number of frames decoded in Video: 119391

**System 2:**
OS: Windows 7 (x64)
Matlab Version: 2013b
Media Package installed: ffMpeg
Number of frames decoded in Video: 119653

It appears the difference in frame counts is because of different codecs being used in the two cases?

How can I align the H264 decoder versions in the two cases? In case I install ffmpeg on System 1, how do I configure Matlab to use that particular decoding library.

And also I would like to know why two different codecs should yield different number of frames on decoding the same video clip!!

Comment: Do both codecs report the same frame rate? One could be rounding 29.97 fps up to 30 possibly. What is the duration of the video as reported by VLC, QuickTime, Matlab's `mmfileinfo`, `get(OBJ)` (where `OBJ` is a VideoReader object), etc.?